# How to reorder cells under UITests?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

Along with `UITests` and `UITableView` I need to reorder cells. Is it possible? I tried `myTable.swipeDown()` but it is called in that place of cell which do not respond for reordering. How can I do this? Is it possible at all?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have set the accessibility properties of the custom cell set correctly then the reorder control should be accessible. Let's assume the cell's set their accessibility labels/identifiers to "LondonStreet" and "BakerStreet", respectively.

You can reorder the cells by tapping and dragging from one reorder control to the next. The accessibility identifier for these controls is set automatically from the cell's information.

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
app.launch()

let topButton = app.buttons["Reorder LondonStreet"]
let bottomButton = app.buttons["Reorder BakerStreet"]
bottomButton.pressForDuration(0.5, thenDragToElement: topButton)
```

The `"Reorder "` prefix was set by the OS. Try using the Accessibility Inspector to see what your reorder control's values are.

[image: Using the Accessibility Inspector to access the reorder control]

I've added an example to my [UI Testing Cheat Sheet](https://github.com/joemasilotti/UI-Testing-Cheat-Sheet#reordering-table-cells) with some [working sample code](https://github.com/joemasilotti/UI-Testing-Cheat-Sheet/blob/80d28d39c06687d6fb298390b6c3dafb19dc255b/UITests/UITests.swift#L78) if you would like to try it on your machine.

Comment: How exactly can I check my prefix for cell? How to turn accessibility inspector on?

Comment: Accessibility Inspector is an app installed on your machine, located in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications`. This tool can show your what the prefixes are for your cells.

Comment: I set accessibility identifier to cell, but reorder button does not have an accessibility identifier. It gets its label from the title of the label inside the cell.

Answer (score 0):

To enable `Accessibility Inspector`  first you have to go to:

**System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy**:

[image]

And then **Xcode** > **Open Developer Tool** > **Accessibility Inspector**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

#### A more generic solution: (if you don't know the titles)

```
guard let firstCell = app.cells.allElementsBoundByIndex.first, let topButton = firstCell.buttons.allElementsBoundByIndex.last else { XCTFail("no reoder btn for first cell"); return }
guard let bottomCell = app.cells.allElementsBoundByIndex.last, let bottomButton = bottomCell.buttons.allElementsBoundByIndex.last else { XCTFail("no reoder btn for last cell"); return }
topButton.press(forDuration: 0.5, thenDragTo: bottomButton)
```

Comment: How does this code press on reorder buttons instead of on cells themselves?