# iOS UITests: accessing reordering control elements of UITableViewCells that contain dynamic contents

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xcode-ui-testing

I am writing UITests for reordering of table view cells. This post shows how to do exactly that: [How to reorder cells under UITests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32502633/how-to-reorder-cells-under-uitests), with one problem: it assumes that the accessibility identifiers of the reorder controls are static texts.

The texts on the labels of my cells change every 30 seconds. In order to be able to access the cells in a stable way I explicitly set the accessibility identifiers for all my cells to static strings: "cell1", "cell2", "cell3", etc. Using these identifiers I can successfully access the cells in my UITests. However, the reordering control elements' identifiers remain the OS default values, i.e., "Reorder dynamic_cell_label_text", based on the label content on the cell at the time of access which keeps changing, making accessing the reordering controls for UI testing impossible.

Is there anyway to either 1) change the accessibility values of the reordering control elements or 2) accessing the reordering control elements not by their identifiers, but through the cell it's associated with? Any other ideas are also appreciated.

Comment: If you also set the accessibility label (say to the same thing as the accessID) do you get the same situation?

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the cell element consistently, then you can search for descendant elements of that cell.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/xctest/xcuielement/1500791-descendants